# Alertview for textfiled works on ios7 but not working on ios6.1

Tags: xcode

```
    if ([district.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please fill the fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if([myTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {

        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please fill the fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if ([catname.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {

        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please fill the fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if([msg.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please fill the fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
```

This is my code it works perfectly in ios7 but not in ios6. what changes should I make to work it on ios 6.1

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily alter the view hierarchy of a UIAlertView in iOS 7. (Nor should you; the documentation specifically tells you not to.) Head over to the developer forums to see a long discussion about it.

One alternative in your case is to set **alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;** This will add a text field for you. You can access it in the **UIAlertView delegate** callback by using **UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];**.

Example:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                              message:@"enter your details:"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    /* Display a numerical keypad for this text field */
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

[alertView show];
```